# Load predefined options in select2 jQuery

Tags: jquery, laravel, html-select

Used select2 library in Laravel framework for auto search on select box.

My select box code:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-3" id="zipblock">
  <select class="form-control" id="contactzipcode" name='contactzipcode' disabled>
    <option value=''>--Zip Code--</option>
    @if(isset($zips)) @foreach ($zips as $zipnew)
    <option value="{{ $zipnew->zip_id }}" {{( isset($zip_id) && $zipnew->zip_id == $zip_id) ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $zipnew->zip_code }}</option>
    @endforeach @endif
  </select>
</div>
```

And my script is:

```
$('#contactzipcode').select2({
  ajax: {
    delay: 250,
    url: APP_URL + '/load_zip',
    type: "post",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: function(params) {
      return {
        _token: $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
        search: params.term,
      };
    },
    processResults: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      return {
        results: $.map(data, function(item) {
          return {
            text: item.zip_code,
            id: item.zip_id,
          }
        })
      };
    },
    cache: true
  },
});
```

And my controller for loading options is:

```
public function loadZip(Request $request)
{
  $zip_codes=[];
  if(isset($request->search) && $request->search!=null){
    $zip_codes = ZipCode::select('zip_code','zip_id')->where('zip_code','like', '%' . $request->search . '%')->take(100)->get();
  }

  return response()->json($zip_codes);
}
```

The problem I was faced is options are visible only after search and the select box values options are there but invisible to the user. Only AJAX results are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

there is problem with your controller code if you are not getting the search parameter then there is empty array

try like this

```
      $search = $request->search;

      if($search == ''){
         $user = User::orderby('name','asc')
                      ->select('id','name')->limit(5)->get();
      }else{
         $user = User::orderby('name','asc')
                 ->select('id','name')
                 ->where('name', 'like', '%' .$search . '%')
                 ->limit(5)->get();
      }
```